# Asp.net MVC 4 Viewbag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewbag

In Controller

```
ViewBag.Category = new SelectList(db.categories, "CategoryID", "CategoryName");
```

In View

```
@foreach (string c in ViewBag.Category)
{
    <li><a href="" link="#">c.CategoryName</a></li>
}
```

I have some problem to display the ViewBag. I want to display the content in the ViewBag of list of Category.

Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Without casting your viewbag data to selecList, it doesnt work. To do this, you need to do following :

`@foreach (var x in (SelectList)ViewBag.Category)
{
    //TODO (eg x.Items you can get Ccategories)
}`